# Restrict Android Studio's layout editor to a specific API level

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is there a way to restrict Android layout editor to generate attributes for a specific API level?

I am dragging and dropping and looking at the generated XML. Though I chose "API level 16" on the preview dropdown, it seems Android Studio still adds attributes like "layout_alignParentStart" which are API Level 17. Is there a way to restrict the elements it adds to API Level 16.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Part of my project's gradle configuration:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.github.dht.holodeck"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
...
```

Comment: Do you have API level 16 set as your `minSdkVersion` in your app's build.gradle?

Comment: Yes. Added my relevant gradle config.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't think this would cause it, but if your compiling with API 23, you should probably use 23.0.2 as your `buildToolsVersion`, 19.1.0 is quite old at this point.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the tip. I am targeting Android 4.1.2. I am using Version 1.5.1 of Android Studio.